# Synchronized Selections

Tags: vega-lite

Can someone show me how to use signals to synchronize two selections within two `vconcat` plots which share the same data?

1. The selection of the first plot is [bound](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/bind.html#scale-binding) to its scales (interactive) and tied to the `x` encoding.
2. The selection of the second plot is tied to the `x` encoding.

At no time should the selections differ.

This is known as *overview+detail* display. Unlike the [scale domain](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html#scale-domains) method it is bidirectional. See the performance plots of Chrome's developer tools for an example. You can use the [scale domain](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html#scale-domains) example as a baseline:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/sp500.csv"},
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "selection": {
        "s1": {
          "type": "interval",
          "encodings": ["x"],
          "bind": "scales"
        }
      },
      "width": 480,
      "mark": "area",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {"title": ""}
        },
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "selection": {
        "s2": {
          "type": "interval",
          "encodings": ["x"]
        }
      },
      "width": 480,
      "height": 60,
      "mark": "area",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {
          "field": "price",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"tickCount": 3, "grid": false}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*Edit*: Doing this in JavaScript does *not* work:

```js
vegaEmbed('#vis', vegalitespec).then(function(result) {
    result.view.addDataListener("s1_store", async function(name, value) {
        if (Object.is(value[0], result.view.data("s2_store")[0]))
            return;
        await result.view.data("s2_store", value).runAsync();
    });
    result.view.addDataListener("s2_store", async function(name, value) {
        if (Object.is(value[0], result.view.data("s1_store")[0]))
            return;
        await result.view.data("s1_store", value).runAsync();
    });
}).catch(console.error);
```

*Edit*: This may not be possible due to the nested scopes of `vconcat`. I can wire a one-way binding as with [scale domains](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html#scale-domains); the reverse remains elusive. Still, a few approaches remain untested. Such as creating a nested signal handler in either JavaScript or Vega (assuming outer scopes are accessible), or patching VegaLite to push the "s1_x" signal to the outer scope.

```js
vegaEmbed('#vis', vegalitespec3).then(async function(result) {
  result.view.addSignalListener("s1", function(name, value){
    result.view.signal("s2_date", value.date);
    result.view.runAsync();
  });
                
  result.view.addSignalListener("s2", function(name, value){
    // todo: handle bounds / null
    if (!value.date)
      return;
    // This does not work with individual plots. Maybe it has
    // been rewired as writable in vconcat plots. Result: nope.
    //result.view.signal("s1", value);
    // Thanks to nested scopes, "s1_x" is not available.
    //result.view.signal("s1_x", value.date.map(result.view.scale("concat_1_x")));
    // How about editing the runtime dataflow object? Result: nope.
    //result.view._runtime.subcontext[1].signals.s1_x.value = value.date.map(result.view.scale("concat_1_x"));
    result.view.runAsync();
  });

}).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Ah, vega-editor has signal viewer; makes figuring this stuff easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

1. Patch the generated Vega to push the "s1_x" signal to the outer scope.
2. Add signal listeners to update the selections of each respective plot.
3. Use the scales to convert from data-space to plot-space.
4. Use a barrier boolean to prevent infinite looping.

```js
%%javascript
window.vegalitespec3 = {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"url": vegaDatasets["sp500.csv"].url},
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "selection": {
        "s2": {
          "type": "interval",
          "encodings": ["x"],
          "bind": "scales"
        }
      },
      "width": 480,
      "mark": "area",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {"title": ""}
        },
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "selection": {
        "s1": {
          "type": "interval",
          "encodings": ["x"]
        }
      },
      "width": 480,
      "height": 60,
      "mark": "area",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {
          "field": "price",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"tickCount": 3, "grid": false}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
%%HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>.vega-embed.has-actions {width:90%}</style>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@4"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-datasets"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="vis"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    vegaEmbed( '#vis', vegalitespec3, {"patch": spec => {
        spec.signals.push({"name": "s1_x", "value": []});
        var s_s1_x = spec.marks.find(i => i.name == "concat_1_group")
                         .signals.find(i => i.name == "s1_x");
        delete s_s1_x.value;
        s_s1_x.push = "outer";
        return spec;
    }}).then(function(result) {
        result.locals = {"barrier": true};
        
        result.view.addSignalListener("s1", function(name, value){
            result.locals.barrier = !result.locals.barrier;
            if (!result.locals.barrier)
                return;
            result.view.signal("s2_date", value.date);
            result.view.runAsync();
        });
                
        result.view.addSignalListener("s2", function(name, value){
            result.locals.barrier = !result.locals.barrier;
            if (!result.locals.barrier)
                return;
            value = value.date ? value.date.map(result.view.scale("concat_1_x")) : [];
            result.view.signal("s1_x", value);
            result.view.runAsync();
        });
    }).catch(console.error);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```